# Tableau Sever - Identify link between views and connections

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am new to tableau and my org has provided me access to tableau server. When I log into the server, I see 2 tabs views and connections (snapshot below). However, I am unable to identify which view uses which connection. Is there any way to identify which view is using which connection?

PS: My org will not provide me a tableau desktop license.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without a Tableau Desktop, the best way to associate each view to the relevant data source would probably be to open each view and look for the data source icon (as you can see in the screenshot posted below). If you move your cursor on it, it will show you the name of the data source used.

[image: Tableau Server data source icon]